# MVVM Light SimpleIoC vs Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, inversion-of-control, mvvm-light

I'm working on a new project with MVVM Light. I've heard you best don't use the included SimpleIoC  because of several limitations. But what are the disadvantages/limitations of using SimpleIoC?

What advantages does using Ninject have when making this choice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My official line is "SimpleIoc is probably enough for many applications, especially mobile ones. If you need more features, or if you have an IOC container that you prefer, you can swap it".

I never encountered scenarios that I couldn't solve with SimpleIoc except on some WPF desktop apps where we needed to configure the IOC container with a config file, which SimpleIoc does not support.

Hope this helps,
Laurent